# Azure devops service connection and central pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, serviceconnection

I have a requirement of giving multiple teams access to a shared resource in azure. I therefore want to limit how people can publish changes to the shared resource.

The idea is to limit the use of a service connection to a specific pipeline, [as per this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). However if the pipeline is stored in their own repo the developer could change it. This would not give me enough control. I therefore found that it was possible [using a template from a central repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories). Using a shared repo, would then allow me to have a service connection solely for the template?

So how I imagine doing the above is I need to grant project X a service connection for my BuildTemplates Repo. But this is basically just access to the repo and to be able to use the shared templates. Then in BuildTemplates repo I can have a service connection for my template A.

Now the developer in project X - creates her deployments and configurations for her pipeline with her own service connection scoped for her resources. Then she inherits a template from BuildTemplates Repo and passes relevant parameters for the template A.

She cannot alter the template pipeline A and only the template pipeline A can publish to the shared resource, because of the scoped service connection. I can therefore create relevant guards for the shared azure resource in the template pipeline A - so I restrict how developer X can publish to my shared azure resource.

- does this make sense and is it viable?
- The pipeline part in A cannot be edited by developer in X ?
- The service connection in A will not propagate out so developer in X can use it in an inappropriate way?

### Update

The above solution does not seem to be viable since the pipeline template is executed in the source branch scope.

### Proposed Solution

The benefits I see with the above suggestion doe not seem possible, because of the issues. However one can utilise pipeline triggers, as a viable solution. This however results in a new issue. When a pipeline is triggered by Developer Y in Y's repository and it succeeds. Then a trigger is made in MAIN repository and the pipeline in MAIN fails e.g., because the artifacts from Y introduced an Issue. How does developer Y get notified about the issues in MAIN pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, in same Azure organization, we can create a Azure Project, then create a repo to save common pipeline template.
All the repos in other Azure project can access this pipeline template.

[image]

UserProject/UserRepo/azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - nuget.config
    - README.md
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - .gitignore

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: devops-tools
    type: git
    name: PipelineTemplateProject/CommonPipeline
    ref: 'refs/heads/master'

jobs:
- template: template-pipeline.yml@devops-tools
```

PipelineTemplateProject/CommonPipeline/template-pipeline.yml

Since the inline script of pipeline has 5000 characters limitation,
you can put your script(not only powershell, but also other languages) in PipelineTemplateProject/CommonPipeline/scripts/test.ps1

```
# Common Pipeline Template
jobs:
 - job: Test_Job
   pool:
     name: AgentPoolName
   steps:
   - script: |
       echo "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
       echo "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
       git config user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
       git config user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
       git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
       echo '------------------------------------'
       git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -b $(ToolsRepoBranch) --single-branch --depth=1 "https://PipelineTemplateProject/_git/CommonPipeline" DevOps_Tools
       echo '------------------------------------'
     displayName: 'Clone DevOps_Tools'

   - task: PowerShell@2
     displayName: 'Pipeline Debug'
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: 'Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\ | Format-List'
     condition: always()

   - task: PowerShell@2
     displayName: 'Run Powershell Scripts'
     inputs:
       targetType: filePath
       filePath: 'DevOps_Tools/scripts/test.ps1'
       arguments: "$(System.AccessToken)"
```

Notes:
Organization Setting - Settings - Disable Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines

Organization Setting - Settings - Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines

Check some option in project setting as well.

[image]

So the normal user only access their own repo, cannot access DevOps project, and DevOps owner can edit template pipeline only.

For the notification issue, I use an Email extention "rvo.SendEmailTask.send-email-build-task.SendEmail@1"

Comment: Do you have a simple example of github of this?